# MySQL Why does mysqldump break/just stop? Improve my mysqldump command

Tags: mysqldump

I use the following command to backup my MySQL (with mysqldumpl) two times a day:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldumpl --lock-tables=false --default-character-set=utf8 -h'host' -u'user' -p'pass' -f -v db266991x2616700 | gzip > /Volumes/Backups/backup.sql.gz
```

I just found out, that the mysqldump is often incomplete. The file is written, but the file sizes vary. Sometimes the backup file is 20 - 30 % smaller than other backup files.

All files end with `-- Dump completed on ...`, but they are incomplete and just stop in the middle of creating the insert command for a very large table:

```
LOCK TABLES `log_mail` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `log_mail` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `log_mail` VALUES (................................STOPS SOMEWHERE HERE
```

1. What could be the reason for that? Could be a reason, that the database is in use and I don't lock the tables?
2. How can I prevent this? Is there a way to check for errors and repeat the backup in case of an error? It is important that I have a reliable way to backup the database several times a day without checking every backup manually.
3. It is an InnoDB, so I just found out that might be a better command:
   `mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables some_database > some_database.sql` 
   Is this right? What would be the best/right way?
4. Before my question was closed on stackoverflow one comment said: `"I suggest you redirect stderr to a file and also check the return status code"` How would I do that?

Comment: this looks more like a timeout problem, how do you run from a ssh shell?

Comment: @nbk Thanks for your comment. It is a sh-script which runs from a remote MacServer via cronjob.

Comment: stderr see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file

Comment: did you check the error logs

Comment: I used this command manually from the terminal:
`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldumpl --lock-tables=false --default-character-set=utf8 -h'host' -u'user' -p'pass' -f -v db266991x2616700 | gzip > /Volumes/Backups/backup.sql.gz >> log_file 2>> /Volumes/Backups/error.log `
Now I get the error message within the terminal after the dump has started and was running a while: "MySQL server has gone away (2006)". 
But no error log is written and now the backup file is 0 MB. So I don't know if it is the same issue.

Comment: the server times out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html